# Applying a Logical Calculation to Two Vectors and Returning the Result in a Third Vector

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R and am having trouble implementing something that should be very basic.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

I need to apply a logical calculation based on the values of two vectors and return the value of that function in a third vector.

I want to do this in a user defined function so I can easily apply this in several other areas of the algorithm and make modifications to the implementation with ease.

Here's what I have tried, but I cannot get this implementation to work.  I believe it is because I cannot send vectors as parameters to this function.

```
<!-- language: python -->
calcSignal <- function(fVector, sVector) {
  if(!is.numeric(fVector) || !is.numeric(sVector)) {
    0
  }
  else if (fVector > sVector) {
    1
  }
  else if (fVector < sVector) {
    -1
  }
  else {
    0  # is equal case        
  }
}

# set up data frame
df <- data.frame(x=c("NA", 2, 9, 7, 0, 5), y=c(4, 1, 5, 9, 0, "NA"))
# call function
df$z <- calcSignal(df$x, df$y)
```

I want the output to be a vector with the following values, but I am not implementing the function correctly.

[0,-1,1,-1,0,0]

Can someone help explain how to implement this function to properly perform the logic outlined?

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: This should be an easy one, but your example data is all characters - you need to remove the `"NA"` and make them `NA` instead.

Comment: Look into `?ifelse`. There are probably more elegant methods, but nesting a couple of these will get the job done. `if` expects a single value, so your `ifelse` stuff doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misunderstandings in your code:

1. in R, "NA" is considered as character (string is called character in R). the correct 
   form is NA without quotes. 
   it is worth noting that data.frame automatically will convert character to factor type which can be disabled by using `data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors = F)`.
2. each column of a data.frame has a type, not each element. so when you have a column containing numbers and NA, class of that column will be numeric and `is.numeric` gives you `True` even for NA elements. `is.na` will do the job
3. `||` only compares first element of each vector. `|` does elementwise comparison.

Now let's implement what you wanted:
**Implementation 1**:

```
#set up data frame
df <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 2, 9, 7, 0, 5), y=c(4, 1, 5, 9, 0, NA))

calcSignal <- function(f,s){
  if(is.na(f) | is.na(s))
    return(0)
  else if(f>s)
    return(1)
  else if(f<s)
    return(-1)
  else
    return(0)
}
df$z = mapply(calcSignal, df$x, df$y, SIMPLIFY = T)
```

to run a function on two or more vectors element-wise, we can use `mapply`.

**Implementaion 2**
not much different from previous. here the function is easier to use.

```
#set up data frame
df <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 2, 9, 7, 0, 5), y=c(4, 1, 5, 9, 0, NA))

calcSignal <- function(fVector, sVector) {
  res = mapply(function(f,s){
    if(is.na(f) | is.na(s))
      return(0)
    else if(f>s)
      return(1)
    else if(f<s)
      return(-1)
    else
      return(0)
  },fVector,sVector,SIMPLIFY = T)
  return(res)
}
df$z = calcSignal(df$x,df$y)
```

**Implementaion 3 (Vectorized)**
This one is much better. because it is vectorized and is much faster:

```
calcSignal <- function(fVector, sVector) {
  res = rep(0,length(fVector))
  res[fVector>sVector] = 1
  res[fVector<sVector] = -1

  #This line isn't necessary.It's just for clarification
  res[(is.na(fVector) | is.na(sVector))] = 0

  return(res)
}
df$z = calcSignal(df$x,df$y)
```

Output:

```
> df
   x  y  z
1 NA  4  0
2  2  1  1
3  9  5  1
4  7  9 -1
5  0  0  0
6  5 NA  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Adel_Sa!  I used implementation #3 and it works perfectly.  I also appreciate you taking the time to point out some flaws in my code (like the NA and or operator).  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

No need for loopage as `?sign` has your back:

```
# fixing the "NA" issue:
df <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 2, 9, 7, 0, 5), y=c(4, 1, 5, 9, 0, NA))

s <- sign(df$x - df$y)
s[is.na(s)] <- 0
s
#[1]  0  1  1 -1  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` is another handy function. Less elegant here than `sign` though

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 2, 9, 7, 0, 5), y=c(4, 1, 5, 9, 0, NA))

cs <- function(x, y){
  a <- x > y
  b <- x < y

  out <- ifelse(a, 1, ifelse(b, -1, 0))

  ifelse(is.na(out), 0, out)

}
cs(df$x, df$y)
```